# What does downforce upgrade actually do to your car?

Tags: hill-climb-racing-2

"Upgraded aerodinamics give a nice downforce effect" but this doesn't cut it for me. Does it make go quicker, similar to the gearbox effect, or does it make fly less, or something else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that down force helps long term acceleration and grip.

I performed a very unofficial test with 0 down force and 5 or 6 levels of down force. The outcome: with the upgrades my shadow I'm accelerating faster, compared to my shadow I was testing against. Also I finally managed to go up a certain hill, and that was all due to grip, not acceleration.

Other answers welcomed though.

Answer (score 1):

It pushes you down with more force and more rapidly.

This comes in handy for instance when you participate in a race with a penalty for air time. Having your car pushed to the ground makes it easier for you not to lose time.

Another scenario where I found downforce useful is in the tarmac races with many hills. Sometimes, withouth downforce, if you jump over from one hill to just a little below the top of the one that follows you just bump on it and lose your momentum. In the other hand with downforce, you can proceed a little quicker and the downforce will push you down to the valley where you'll have plenty of road to acquire speed to climb the hill.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that it makes you:

1. Go faster down hills meaning you have more momentum for the next hill/jump
2. Become not as likely to fly or bounce on small bumps, and yes, get less air time.